# How to merge elements in objects inside of array and returned unique objects with updated data

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function, object

my question is how I can merge elements in array of objects and return array with unique objects. I was trying to use reduce but it's looks like I missing something and it's time to ask for hint.
So how you can see I need merge elements of boolean where false is default value and true is new data, and return unique objects based on name. Thank you for help.

```
const arr = [
    {
      code: 'test1',
      name: 'TEST1',
      url: '/test1',
      elements: {
        option1: true,
        option2: false,
        option3: false,
        option4: false,
        option5: false
      }
    },
      {
        code: 'test1',
        name: 'TEST1',
        url: '/test1',
        elements: {
          option1: false,
          option2: false,
          option3: true,
          option4: false,
          option5: false
      }
      },
        {
        code: 'test1',
        name: 'TEST1',
        url: '/test1',
        elements: {
          option1: false,
          option2: false,
          option3: false,
          option4: true,
          option5: false
      }
      },
       {
        code: 'test2',
        name: 'TEST2',
        url: '/test2',
        elements: {
          option1: false,
          option2: false,
          option3: true,
          option4: false,
          option5: false
      }
      },
    ]
```

and output it should be:

```
const arr = [
    {
      code: 'test1',
      name: 'TEST1',
      url: '/test1',
      elements: {
        option1: true,
        option2: false,
        option3: true,
        option4: true,
        option5: false
      }
    },
       {
        code: 'test2',
        name: 'TEST2',
        url: '/test2',
        elements: {
          option1: false,
          option2: false,
          option3: true,
          option4: false,
          option5: false
      }
      },
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working on the assumption that `elements` is the only thing that actually varies here, and that you can't switch back from `false` to `true` (since that what it seems like you are going for), you'd need to iterate over the key-value pairs in elements and set it to the `originalValue || newValue`, so something like this:

```js
const arr = [
    {
      code: 'test1',
      name: 'TEST1',
      url: '/test1',
      elements: {
        option1: true,
        option2: false,
        option3: false,
        option4: false,
        option5: false
      }
    },
      {
        code: 'test1',
        name: 'TEST1',
        url: '/test1',
        elements: {
          option1: false,
          option2: false,
          option3: true,
          option4: false,
          option5: false
      }
      },
        {
        code: 'test1',
        name: 'TEST1',
        url: '/test1',
        elements: {
          option1: false,
          option2: false,
          option3: false,
          option4: true,
          option5: false
      }
      },
       {
        code: 'test2',
        name: 'TEST2',
        url: '/test2',
        elements: {
          option1: false,
          option2: false,
          option3: true,
          option4: false,
          option5: false
      }
      },
    ].reduce((carry, current) => {
        const existing = carry.find(item => item.code === current.code);
        if (!existing) {
            carry.push(current);
        } else {
            Object.entries(current.elements).forEach(([k, v]) => {
                existing.elements[k] = existing.elements[k] || current.elements[k];
            });
        }
        return carry;
    }, []);
    
    console.log(arr);
```